# Combine lists using for loop

Tags: python

How do I combine a set of 3 lists using a for loop in python?

Input:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ['Combine','list']
list3 = ['using','for','loop']
```

Desired Output

```
list_comb = [1,2,3,'Combine','list','using','for','loop']
```

Comment: using `+`, `list1 + list2 + list3`

Comment: the problem needs to be solved using a for loop only

Comment: then show us what you've tried. It should not be difficult given you know how to use loops and you're aware of the [`.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) function.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list1+list2+list3
[1, 2, 3, 'Combine', 'list', 'using', 'for', 'loop']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, just put all of your lists into a list then iterate through

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ['Combine','list']
list3 = ['using','for','loop']
listset = [list1, list2, list3]
list_comb = []
for lists in listset:
    list_comb += lists

print(list_comb)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 'Combine', 'list', 'using', 'for', 'loop']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ['Combine','list']
list3 = ['using','for','loop']

#initializing an empty list to fill it with our desired items
list_comb = []

for item in list1+list2+list3:
    #adding item to our list_comb
    list_comb.append(item)

print(list_comb)
```